# JSON/CURL issue

Tags: php, json, curl

My CURL request takes in two variables as shown below:

```
<?php
$id             =       $_GET["id"];
$review         =       $_GET["review"];
$url = 'http://edward/~treeves/ratingJSON.php';

$jsonData = array("id" => "$id", "review" => "$review");

$ch = curl_init($url);

$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json' => $jsonDataEncoded));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

And posts it to the web service shown below:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");


    try {
        $conn           =       new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=treeves;", "treeves", "oopheiye");
        $json           =       $_POST["json"];
        $data           =       json_decode ($json, true);      
        $result         =       $conn->query("INSERT INTO poi_reviews (poi_id, review) 
                                              VALUES ('$data[ID]', '$data[review]')");

        } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

However the data being inserted is blank. When I use `var_dump($data)` on the web service is shows `1 NULL`. I think it's to do with the variables in the CURL file as the web service works. Any ideas?

**Update**
Taking out the HTTP header and using 'var_dump($data, $error === JSON_ERROR_UTF8)' is returning the following:

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1014" ["review"]=> string(1) "2" } bool(false)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `json_last_error()` right after the decode in your webservice ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php Also, what is the content of your `$_POST` variable ?

Comment: It returns 'NULL bool(false)'

Comment: try to remove the httpheader ?

Comment: returns 'array(2) { ["id"]=> string(4) "id" ["review"]=> string(1) "review" } bool(false)'

Comment: Why not test one side of the system in isolation? This doesn't need to be a PHP question _and_ a curl question _and_ a JSON question.

Comment: Apologies for my naivety but people often want the whole system to make it easier to comprehend. It is a JSON question in that retrospect.

Comment: Are you saying that `vardump($_POST)` returns `array(2) { ["id"]=> string(4) "id" ["review"]=> string(1) "review" } bool(false)` ?

Comment: '532' is the selected ID and 'hello' is the user input in the following example: array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "523" ["review"]=> string(5) "hello" } bool(false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you set up form encoded data with one key (json) that has a value (of JSON encoded data):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json' => $jsonDataEncoded));
```

Here you tell the server that you are sending JSON and not form encoded data.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

One of the above has to be wrong, since they are contradictory.

---

Here you try to read form encoded data:

```
$_POST["json"];
```

So claiming you are sending plain JSON is wrong (your JSON is encapsulated in form encoding).

Remove this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```